# Adding custom Response Body encoding serverless yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I have yaml for my APIs deployment using serverless, everything is running nice and fine, There is requirements about response body encoding in "text/html; charset=utf-8",

```
events:
- http:
    path: test/test2
    method: post
    private: false
    integration: lambda
    request:
      template:
        application/x-www-form-urlencoded: '#set($inputRoot = $input.path("$")) '
    response:
      statusCodes:            
        200:
          pattern: ''
          headers:
            charset: "'utf-8'"
```

what i need to achieve is showed in below image (its actually aws APIGATEWAY - Method Response Image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WAWn.jpg

Gone through server-less Documentation, but haven't found anything useful, 
any hint ??

Thanks

Comment: did you got any success ??? i am stuck with the same problem and couldn't find anything in documentation

Comment: you can try with this https://github.com/9cookies/serverless-aws-documentation

Comment: did you find anything successful ?? @KuldeepK.Rishi

Comment: yeah was able to achieve the results with this https://github.com/9cookies/serverless-aws-documentation